# Getting : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: spring, spring-mybatis, spring-orm

I am using Spring 3.2.13 jars and ibatis 2.3.4.726 version to set up a dataSource as below

I am getting the below Exception 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

My xml Spring Configurations are as below :

```
<bean id="commonDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/ds_GOLD" />
    <property name="defaultObject" value="jdbc/ds_SILVERR" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>
            classpath:com/dav/dao/config/sqlMapConfig.xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="commonDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionConfigClass">
        <value>com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.external.ExternalTransactionConfig
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionConfigProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="DefaultAutoCommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="SetAutoCommitAllowed">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The Configurations seems good for me but getting exception
only if the "jdbc/ds_GOLD" is not configured in App server. In this case it should get picked the defaultObject JNDI. If the "jdbc/ds_GOLD" is configured in App server i don't see any error in logs. But Failover case it is not working.

```
[5/1/16 3:32:51:329 EDT] 00000098 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0296E: [glow#glow.war][/glow][Servlet.LOG]:.StrutsServlet: null:.org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gcdSqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/common-dao.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    .
    .
    . 
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:449)
    ... 120 more
 ``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget to keep the defaultObject as property reference to the dataSource. I wrongly configured it as property value.